# Tab in second activity replace tab in first activity

Tags: android

i have two activity and every one have different Tab when in second activity and press one tab for Intent to first activity Tab in second Activity replace tab in first activity

java code:

```
    Resources ressources = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, calc.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Android")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.me))
            .setContent(intentAndroid);


   Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Apple")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myket))
            .setContent(intentApple);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

xml:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. It may help you:

```
    public class Test extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

And xml page:

```
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

        <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TabWidget 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```